# Loop and extract files matching a path

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, script

I am currently in a directory with many directories.

```
$ ls
the bad icons 100                 the games icons 100
the beach & camping icons 100          the halloween icons 100
```

How can I extract all pngs that match the following path and output them in a directory?

```
/{iconPackFolderName}/png/colored/512x512/*.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
mv /{iconPackFolderName}/png/colored/512x512/*.png {TargetDirectory}
```

If you get a message that there are too many files and the command is too long, try this

```
echo /{iconPackFolderName}/png/colored/512x512/*.png | xargs mv --target-directory {TargetDirectory}
```

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -n` in any mass move, to avoid silent & irreversible data loss if there are any conflicting names. In this case it *should* be safe, but I don't like to rely on that.

Comment: Doesn't xargs need to be told to do something, like run `mv`? It's default is `echo`. And what happens if there are blank spaces in filenames? xargs input is delimited by blanks/newlines by default. And how does `{iconPackFolderName}` become one of the four folder names (that contain spaces)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already in the directory, you can use `.` with find:

```
find . -path "*/png/colored/512x512/*.png" -exec mv -t TARGETDIR {} +
```

If you want to first look over the found files, remove the `-exec` and following (or replace it with `| less`), find will output the filenames to stdout by default, as in:

```
find . -path "*/png/colored/512x512/*.png" | less
```

You might want `mv`'s `-i, --interactive` option to prompt before overwrite, in case there are conflicting filenames.